# ImageView use app:srcCompat does not render on runtime

Tags: android, vector

Vector file:  global_message_b.xml in /res/drawable/

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="69.0"
android:viewportWidth="69.0" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillAlpha="0.01" android:fillColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:pathData="M0,0h69v69h-69z"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
<path android:fillColor="#00000000"
    android:pathData="M7.35,47.56C8.99,50.58 6.06,57.48 8.68,59.77C11.4,62.15 19.7,59.9 23.2,61.23C26.72,62.56 30.57,63.3 34.6,63.3C51.5,63.3 65.2,50.36 65.2,34.4C65.2,18.44 51.5,5.5 34.6,5.5C17.7,5.5 4,18.44 4,34.4C4,39.14 5.21,43.61 7.35,47.56Z"
    android:strokeColor="#232230" android:strokeWidth="3.4"/>
<path android:fillColor="#E60012"
    android:pathData="M16.15,34.25a4.5,4.5 0,1 0,9 0a4.5,4.5 0,1 0,-9 0z"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
<path android:fillColor="#E60012"
    android:pathData="M29.75,34.25a4.5,4.5 0,1 0,9 0a4.5,4.5 0,1 0,-9 0z"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
<path android:fillColor="#E60012"
    android:pathData="M43.35,34.25a4.5,4.5 0,1 0,9 0a4.5,4.5 0,1 0,-9 0z"
    android:strokeColor="#00000000" android:strokeWidth="1"/>
```

XML :

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"



 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/global_message_b" />
```

The vector drawable render correctly in Android Studio Design Layout.But when i run the app ,the vector not display.But if i change the ImageView to android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView,the vector display correctly in app.

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/global_message_b" />
```

So I want to know should I use vector drawable in AppCompatImageView.If this,why the office android develop post not say this:[Android Support Library 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

Comment: The vector seems to work fine with `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0`  && `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0`. Could you check and see with these latest versions?

Comment: @b1izzard my gradle version is 2.1.0 : com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0,and   com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0

Comment: Which device you are running it?, By default `ImageView` uses `AppCompatImageView` to display images. I hope that's not the issue. Could you get any errors in the logcat while running? Please upload screenshots for the both versions of your Imageview.